# Write plist defaults value inside a named profile

Tags: plist, defaults

How do I write a value inside a named profile, like so;

```
defaults write com.apple.Terminal "'Window Settings'.Basic.shellExitAction" -int 1
```

Obviously this doesn't work and also tried multiple variants, like writing in array/object style with `[name][sub_name]`, but none seems to work and I can't find the logic in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `PlistBuddy` instead;

```
readonly plist_file="${HOME}/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist"

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy "${plist_file}" -c "delete :'Window Settings':Basic:shellExitAction"

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy "${plist_file}" -c "add :'Window Settings':Basic:shellExitAction integer 1"
```